# In CloudFlare how do I stop it from blocking my tumblr blog?

Tags: tumblr, cloudflare

In CloudFlare how do I stop it from blocking my tumblr blog?

I'm using cloudflare for my website blog.
I feed to my website blog articles from tumblr over https.

my cloudflare is https.

is there a setting in cloudflare for allowing my tumblr blog? if so can you provide step my step instructions, as I'm new to cloudflare.

I've also messaged cloudflare and they wont reply to this issue and I've messaged them twice recently.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Cloudflare support article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168566-How-do-I-add-a-Tumblr-custom-domain-), you can use Tumblr with Cloudflare if you setup a custom domain, the catch is that you can't use SSL.

Comments in [this more recent discussion](http://tteoh.com/technology/2015/04/09/cloudflare-and-tumblr/) seem to confirm this, that you can only use Tumblr and Cloudflare without SSL.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Cloudflare to manage the DNS for your domain and point that domain to Cloudflare.

That said; unfortunately Tumblr have indicated they don't support Cloudflare proxying web traffic, their for your DNS records will need to be [grey-clouded](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169626-What-subdomains-are-appropriate-for-orange-gray-clouds-) (meaning no HTTPS, etc).

This is really something in Tumblr's bands, so you may wish to [reach out to them](https://www.tumblr.com/support).